# How can I host multiple node js applications on elastic beanstalk?

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to build a website which links to multiple nodejs apps.

```
www.example.com/app1
www.example.com/app2
```

Both app1 and app2 are hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

```
http://app1.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com
http://app2.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

How can I redirect sub-directories on example.com to these apps without changing the URL in the browser?

Should I create a 3rd app on EBS and associate example.com with it. Then use nginx on it to redirect to specific apps?

Sorry for the vagueness. I'm new to this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by `nginx`. Your config should look like this one:

```
server {
    listen       80;

    location /app1 {
        proxy_pass http://app1.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com:80;
    }

    location /app2 {
        proxy_pass http://app2.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com:80;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried 
`location ^~ /app1/ { rewrite ^/app1/(.*) http://app1.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/$1 permanent; }`
This redirects me to `http://app1.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com` and changes the url in the browser, which I'm trying to avoid. Though, I'm not certain if your solution prevents that. I'll check.

Answer (score 0):

@Alexander Thanks. Though I had issues with static file getting 404
This did the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36849456/nginx-reverse-proxy-404-on-static-files

```
if ($uri ~ app1/) {
  break;
}

if ($http_referer ~ app1/ ) {
  rewrite (.*) /app1/$1 redirect;
}

location /app1/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://app1.compute.amazonaws.com:3001/ ;
}
```

Though as noted in the link. It won't work for POST queries :/